# Conjugation of 이시다

Tags: verb, honorific, conjugation

Could you please tell me if this is correct?

이다  -->  이시다

Present tense

야 / 이야  -->  셔 / 이셔

예요 / 이에요  -->  세요 / 이세요

인다  -->  이시다

입니다  -->  이십니다

Past tense

였어  -->  였셔

였어요  -->  였세요

였다  -->  였시다

였습니다  -->  였십니다

Future tense

일 거야  -->  일 거셔

일 거예요  -->  일 거세요

일 거다  -->  일 거시다

일 겁니다  -->  일 겁십니다

I would greatly appreciate if you could correct what may be wrong.

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

이다 --> 이시다

Present tense

야 / 이야 --> 셔 / 이셔

예요 / 이에요 --> 세요 / 이세요

**이**다 --> 이시다

입니다 --> 이십니다

Past tense

였어 **/ 이었어** --> **셨**어 **/ 이셨어**

였어요 **/ 이었어요** --> **셨**어요 **/ 이셨어요**

였다 **/ 이었다** --> **셨**다 **/ 이셨다**

였습니다 **/ 이었습니다** --> **셨**습니다 **/ 이셨습니다**

Future tense

일 거야 --> **이실** 거야

일 거예요 --> **이실** 거예요

일 거다 --> **이실** 거다

일 겁니다 --> **이실** 겁니다

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It has been really helpful! :)