# Is it possible to use the honorific 으시 in the plain form?

Tags: grammar, honorific

I'm aware the plain form or 해라체 is an impersonal form, so it would be rarely correct to use honorifics in plain form. However, I've found some instances in some textbooks in which saying (으)신다 is correct. But I've hardly found instances in which the honorific is used with the copula 이다, Descriptive verbs in past, or any instance in which it's used in future tense with any verb (descriptive or not).

Thank you very much, I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, addressee honorification ("speech styles") and subject honorification ("using -(으)시-, -께서, ...") are different things you need to consider. You should use -(으)시- when you describe someone "higher" than yourself (although there are exceptional cases). Look at these examples to see how -(으)시- is inserted in several conjugated forms:

- **문**다 (= 물- + -ㄴ다) + **-시-** → **무신**다.
- **굽는**다 (= 굽- + -는다) + **-으시-** → **구우신**다.
- 입**는**다 (= 입- + -는다) + **-으시-** → 입**으신**다.
- **쓴**다 (= 쓰- + -ㄴ다) + **-시-** → **쓰신**다.
- 먹**인**다 (= 먹이- + -ㄴ다) + **-시-** → 먹**이신**다.
- **이**다 + **-시-** → **이시**다.
- **갔**다 (= 가- + -았- + -다)  + **-시-** → **가시었**다 or **가셨**다 (The latter is preferred).
- 도착하겠다 (= 도착하- + -겠- + -다) + **-시-** → 도착하**시**겠다.

As you may have noticed, some endings change when they meet -(으)시-. Dictionaries have grammatical information, so consult them to learn where to use -으시-, -시-, -는다, and -ㄴ다. These are example sentences for all the forms given above:

- 아기는 사탕을 입에 **문다**.
- 할머니는 사탕을 입에 **무신다**.
- 동생이 고기를 **굽는다**.
- 할아버지께서 고기를 **구우신다**.
- 아버지께서 모자를 쓰실 때 나는 바지를 **입는다**.
- 내가 모자를 쓸 때 아버지는 바지를 **입으신다**.
- 아버지께서 바지를 입으실 때 나는 모자를 **쓴다**.
- 내가 바지를 입을 때 아버지는 모자를 **쓰신다**.
- 어머니께서 새에게 모이를 **먹인다**.
- 어머니께서 동생에게 밥을 **먹이신다**.
- 얘가 네 짝꿍**이다**.
- 이분이 네 선생님**이시다**.
- 나는 시장에 **갔다**.
- 부모님은 시장에 **가셨다**.
- 너는 내일 서울에 **도착하겠다**.
- 부모님은 내일 서울에 **도착하시겠다**.

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://korean.stackexchange.com/a/5603/2162), too.

Comment: Thank you so much!